# How To Reverse an Algorithm

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a math based way to find a password that makes the if statement in the below code true. I have written some stuff that brutes its way to an answer but that does not help me to understand how to solve this problem mathematically. The actual password I need to make the if statement true is irrelevant and not what I am asking for. I specifically want some code to get me started or even complete code that I can study to show me how to reverse engineer this algorithm to arrive at the answer using JavaScript.

```
var passed = false;
function checkPass(password) {
    var total = 0;
    var charlist = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        for (var i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
            var countone = password.charAt(i);                           
            var counttwo = (charlist.indexOf(countone));                    
            counttwo++;                                                 
            total *= 17;                                                
            total += counttwo;                                              
        }


    if (total == 248410397744610) {
        passed = true;
        alert(password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple code snippet that will do it:

```
function invertPass(n) {
    var all = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        out = '',
        offset;

    while (n > 0) {
        offset = n % 17;
        out = all.charAt(offset - 1) + out;
        n = (n - offset) / 17;
    }
    return out;
}


function createPass(password) {
    var total = 0;
    var charlist = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        for (var i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
            var countone = password.charAt(i);                           
            var counttwo = (charlist.indexOf(countone));                    
            counttwo++;                                                 
            total *= 17;                                                
            total += counttwo;                                              
        }

    return total;
}

var orig = 'gdclhpdhbied',
    num = createPass(orig);

console.log(invertPass(num) === orig);
```

Comment: With this you would need to generate some passwords to feed through the function calls correct?

Comment: Yes, all it does is take the number and given you the original password.

Comment: Also note that this can only work where the characters are `<= 'p'`, otherwise the modulus overlaps!

Comment: This is very similar to what I had already written. I was attempting to do it in a way that would try different letter combinations at random but it took forever. It did come up with the same result as you have posted here with 502 additional results as well. Thanks for your help with my supposed "homework" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what the function actually does to `total` depending on its input: It multiplies by 17 and adds the position of the current char in the alphabet.

Therefore your `expectedTotal` (e.g. 248410397744610) will be a number divisible by 17 plus the alphabet position of the password's last letter. Use `%` (the modulus operator) to find said position (simply put, the number you need to subtract from `expectedTotal` to make it divisible by 17), then divide by 17 and repeat.

Comment: Looks like the password corresponding to `total == 248410397744610` is `gdclhpdhbied`.

Comment: there should be multiple that would work, 500+ if my math is right. I am not interested in the answer though, what I want to is to write a function that will get me the answers but I am stuck on how to reverse the algorithm.

Comment: @JohnStewart I just told you how to reverse the algorithm.

Comment: I know I am working through it as we speak